# Time difference between rows of a dataframe

Tags: r

I have been zoning in the R part of StackOverflow for quite a while looking for a proper answer but nothing that what saw seems to apply to my problem.
I have a dataset of this format ( I have adapted it for what seems to be the easiest way to work with, but the stop_sequence values are normally just incremental numbers for each stop) :

```
route_short_name    trip_id                     direction_id    departure_time  stop_sequence 
 33A                1.1598.0-33A-b12-1.451.I            1       16:15:00         start
 33A                1.1598.0-33A-b12-1.451.I            1       16:57:00           end
 41C                10.3265.0-41C-b12-1.277.I           1       08:35:00         start
 41C                10.3265.0-41C-b12-1.277.I           1       09:26:00           end
 41C                100.3260.0-41C-b12-1.276.I          1       09:40:00         start
 41C                100.3260.0-41C-b12-1.276.I          1       10:53:00           end
 114                1000.987.0-114-b12-1.86.O           0       21:35:00         start
 114                1000.987.0-114-b12-1.86.O           0       22:02:00           end
 39                 10000.2877.0-39-b12-1.242.I         1       11:15:00         start
 39                 10000.2877.0-39-b12-1.242.I         1       12:30:00           end
```

It is basically a bus trips dataset. All I want is to manage to get the duration of each trip, so something like that:

```
route_short_name    trip_id                    direction_id    duration
33A                1.1598.0-33A-b12-1.451.I            1        42
41C                10.3265.0-41C-b12-1.277.I           1        51
41C                100.3260.0-41C-b12-1.276.I          1        73
114                1000.987.0-114-b12-1.86.O           0        27
39                 10000.2877.0-39-b12-1.242.I         1        75
```

I have tried a lot of things, but in no case have I managed to group the data by trip_id and then working on the two values at each time. I must have misunderstood something, but I do not know what.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also do this without converting to 'wide' format (assuming that the 'stop_sequence' is 'start' followed by 'end' for each 'route_short_name', 'trip_id', and 'direction_id'.

Convert the 'departure_time' to a datetime column, grouped by 'route_short_name', 'trip_id', and 'direction_id', get the `difftime` of the `last` 'departure_time' with that of the 'first' 'departure_time'

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(departure_time = as.POSIXct(departure_time, format = '%H:%M:%S')) %>%
    group_by(route_short_name, trip_id, direction_id) %>%
    summarise(duration = as.numeric(difftime(last(departure_time), first(departure_time), unit = 'min')))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   route_short_name, trip_id [?]
#  route_short_name                     trip_id direction_id duration
#             <chr>                       <chr>        <int>    <dbl>
#1              114   1000.987.0-114-b12-1.86.O            0       27
#2              33A    1.1598.0-33A-b12-1.451.I            1       42
#3               39 10000.2877.0-39-b12-1.242.I            1       75
#4              41C   10.3265.0-41C-b12-1.277.I            1       51
#5              41C  100.3260.0-41C-b12-1.276.I            1       73
```

Comment: Thank you,  it worken perfectly. I did not know of these last() and first() functions!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Right now you have your dataframe in "long" format, but it would be nice to have it in "wide" format to calculate the time difference. Using the `spread` function in the `tidyverse` package will take your data from long to wide. From there you can use the `mutate` function to add the new column you want. `as.numeric(difftime(end,start))` will keep the difference unit in minutes.

```
library(tidyverse)

wide_df <- 
  spread(your_df,key = stop_sequence, value = departure_time) %>% 
  mutate(timediff = as.numeric(difftime(end,start)))
```

If you want to learn more about "tidy" data (and `spread`ing and `gather`ing), see [this link to Hadley's book](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html)

Comment: I feel a bit dumb, I have the book wiithin my favorites... Anyway, @akrun 's solution worked. Your solution needed an origin, and if you know why origin is needed with hms() I would be glad to understand that as well :)